# Difference between Exalt weapons and regular ones?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I obtained some Exalt weapons.

According to the stats (at least those visible on the loadout screen), they seem to be identical to the conventional weapons which are available in unlimited quantity. Do the Exalt weapons have any hidden advantage or do they serve any special purpose except selling them for 1§ each on the grey market?

Comment: Later you will also obtain some Exalt laser weapons. They again appear to be equivalent to the Xcom versions, but they at least serve some purpose.

Comment: They look better! :-)

Answer (score 8):

EXALT weapons are functionally equivalent to the weapons you have available. After a few months EXALT will upgrade to laser-level weaponry, also identical to the laser weapons you can produce, but without having to use resources to manufacture them. You will need to have researched the equivalent laser weapon to be able to use its EXALT counterpart.

When you keep the EXALT weapons, you might receive an offer from a country to buy some of them. I just received an offer of 30§ for 6 EXALT rocket launchers. Not much, but more than you would get when you sell them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Tactically, there is no reason to use them (unless you like their looks), as the stats are identical.  I can't comment on country requests, as I haven't received one yet.

Note as per @Shadur's comment, that their laser stuff is as good as your laser stuff, and can offer  substantial alloy/money savings if you haven't built a full squad's worth by the time EXALT upgrades (though I wouldn't suggest it as a plan).

Comment: It saved me a lot of expenses at a critical time when I could use the exalt laser sniper/heavy rifles and didn't have to spend money I was very short on to build my own.

Comment: Also, the exalt laser weaponry is great for equipping your base personnel with, just in case you get attacked. Unfortunately, using the option to free up items unequips them all.